# Get Character value from KeyCode in JavaScript... then trim

Tags: javascript, jquery, special-characters, keycode

This is what I have now:

```
$("input").bind("keydown",function(e){
    var value = this.value + String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);
}
```

If the `e.keyCode` may not be an ASCII character (<kbd>Alt</kbd>, <kbd>backspace</kbd>, <kbd>del</kbd>, <kbd>arrows</kbd>, etc.)...
I would now need to `trim` these values from `value` somehow (preferably programmatically - not with lookup tables).

I'm using jQuery.

I must use the `keydown` event. `keyPress` doesn't activate for certain keys I need to capture (<kbd>Esc</kbd>, <kbd>del</kbd>, <kbd>backspace</kbd>, etc.).

I cannot use `setTimeout` to get the input's value. `setTimeout(function(){},0)` is too slow.

Comment: You must use `keydown` to capture character codes? You're in for a hell of a ride: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/keys.html (hint: **use `keypress`!!**)

Comment: The case of the character doesn't matter. And I need to capture up,down,left,right,esc,del,backspace for at least FF and IE; so keypress is out of the question. Thanks for the hint though. :-)

Comment: In response to this problem I just wrote a jQuery plugin: https://github.com/bpeacock/key-to-charCode/ It is a bit down and dirty and could be better integrated into jQuery, but it's a start.

Comment: For anyone that came here trying to solve the KeyCode problem but really just wants to see what key was pressed, check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46060900/1717828).  TLDR: `document.onkeydown = function(e){ console.log('Key: ' + e.key); }`

Comment: `keypress` is deprecated and should never be used according to MDN (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/keypress_event). You should always use `keydown` instead. `keydown` now passes `key` which "Returns a string representing the key value of the key represented by the event." - which is similar to what `keypress` used to do. Read more about the `keydown` event on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/keydown_event

Answer (score 170, accepted):

Maybe I didn't understand the question correctly, but can you not use `keyup` if you want to capture both inputs?

```
$("input").bind("keyup",function(e){
    var value = this.value + String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);
});
```

Comment: That doesn't work with other locales which are outside of the ASCII range (such as latin-1 for instance, german, french, italian and spanish if you must know). Also fails for non printable keys, obviously.

Comment: This also fails when using numbers on the number pad, e.keyCode is not the ASCII (or even UTF-x) code.

Comment: Bad answer, it doesn't even work with basic characters. Semicolon keyCode , for example, is 186, run a String.fromCharCode() on it and you will get garbage. The problem is that keyCode does not correspond to ASCII for all characters. The ASCII character for semicolon is 59. Same issue is true of every special character, keyCode does NOT return the right code for String.fromCharCode().

Answer (score 208):

In my experience `String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode)` is unreliable.  `String.fromCharCode` expects unicode charcodes as an argument; `e.keyCode` returns javascript keycodes.  Javascript keycodes and unicode charcodes are *not* the same thing!  In particular, the numberpad keys return a different `keycode` from the ordinary number keys (since they are different keys) while the same `keycode` is returned for both `upper` and `lowercase` letters (you pressed the same key in both cases), despite them having different `charcodes`.

For example, the ordinary number key 1 generates an event with `keycode` 49 while numberpad key 1 (with <kbd>Numlock</kbd> on) generates `keycode` 97.  Used with `String.fromCharCode` we get the following:

```
String.fromCharCode(49) returns "1"
String.fromCharCode(97) returns "a"
```

`String.fromCharCode` expects unicode charcodes, not javascript keycodes.  The key <kbd>a</kbd> generates an event with a `keycode` of 65, independentant of the case of the character it would generate (there is also a modifier for if the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key is pressed, etc. in the event).  The character <kbd>a</kbd> has a unicode `charcode` of 61 while the character <kbd>A</kbd> has a `charcode` of 41 (according to, for example, http://www.utf8-chartable.de/).  However, those are `hex` values, converting to decimal gives us a `charcode` of 65 for "A" and 97 for "a".[1]  This is consistent with what we get from `String.fromCharCode` for these values.

My own requirement was limited to processing numbers and ordinary letters (accepting or rejecting depending on the position in the string) and letting control characters (<kbd>F</kbd>-keys, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-something) through.  Thus I can check for the control characters, if it's not a control character I check against a range and only then do I need to get the actual character.  Given I'm not worried about case (I change all letters to uppercase anyway) and have already limited the range of keycodes, I only have to worry about the numberpad keys.  The following suffices for that:

```
String.fromCharCode((96 <= key && key <= 105)? key-48 : key)
```

More generally, a function to reliably return the character from a `charcode` would be great (maybe as a jQuery plugin), but I don't have time to write it just now.  Sorry.

I'd also mention `e.which` (if you're using jQuery) which normalizes `e.keyCode` and `e.charCode`, so that you don't need to worry about what sort of key was pressed.  The problem with combining it with `String.fromCharCode` remains.

[1] I was confused for a while -. all the docs say that `String.fromCharCode` expects a unicode `charcode`, while in practice it seemed to work for ASCII charcodes, but that was I think due to the need to convert to decimal from hex, combined with the fact that ASCII charcodes and unicode decimal charcodes overlap for ordinary latin letters.

Comment: This comment pretty much sovled all my problems.  It's amazing to me that jQuery has not implemented a "fromKeyCode" equivalent to javascript's "String.fromCharCode"

Comment: It seems that the KeyPress event does this.  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/9350415/209568.  From the jQuery docs "Note that keydown and keyup provide a code indicating which key is pressed, while keypress indicates which character was entered. For example, a lowercase "a" will be reported as 65 by keydown and keyup, but as 97 by keypress. An uppercase "A" is reported as 65 by all events. Because of this distinction, when catching special keystrokes such as arrow keys, .keydown() or .keyup() is a better choice."

Comment: This is most unpleasant for those of us who are addicted to keydown.

Comment: A note on that last bit about ASCII and Unicode. Unicode has all 128 ASCII characters in the same place. This was intentional so that any file  originally encoded as ASCII can masquerade as (and be converted to) Unicode with no work required. Extended ASCII characters are not in the same place though, so if you used those characters you're out of luck.

Comment: The point of `keyCode` is to know what key was pressed, not to know what character to use. For instance, "U" on a Dvorak keyboard has the same keycode as "F" on a QWERTY keyboard or "ㄹ" on a Korean keyboard etc. The point is not to convert it into a character, it is there so that you can easily map things to a keyboard position.

Answer (score 94):

## Readable key names indexed by key code

There are relatively few key codes so I simply listed all the corresponding values in a static array so I could simply convert the number `65` into `A` using `keyboardMap[65]`

**Not all key codes map to a printable character so some other identifiable string is returned.**

You may need to modify the array to suit your needs and can simply return empty strings for all the characters you don't care to translate.  The following array allows me to quickly and reliably determine which key was pressed in any environment.  Enjoy!

```
// names of known key codes (0-255)

var keyboardMap = [
  "", // [0]
  "", // [1]
  "", // [2]
  "CANCEL", // [3]
  "", // [4]
  "", // [5]
  "HELP", // [6]
  "", // [7]
  "BACK_SPACE", // [8]
  "TAB", // [9]
  "", // [10]
  "", // [11]
  "CLEAR", // [12]
  "ENTER", // [13]
  "ENTER_SPECIAL", // [14]
  "", // [15]
  "SHIFT", // [16]
  "CONTROL", // [17]
  "ALT", // [18]
  "PAUSE", // [19]
  "CAPS_LOCK", // [20]
  "KANA", // [21]
  "EISU", // [22]
  "JUNJA", // [23]
  "FINAL", // [24]
  "HANJA", // [25]
  "", // [26]
  "ESCAPE", // [27]
  "CONVERT", // [28]
  "NONCONVERT", // [29]
  "ACCEPT", // [30]
  "MODECHANGE", // [31]
  "SPACE", // [32]
  "PAGE_UP", // [33]
  "PAGE_DOWN", // [34]
  "END", // [35]
  "HOME", // [36]
  "LEFT", // [37]
  "UP", // [38]
  "RIGHT", // [39]
  "DOWN", // [40]
  "SELECT", // [41]
  "PRINT", // [42]
  "EXECUTE", // [43]
  "PRINTSCREEN", // [44]
  "INSERT", // [45]
  "DELETE", // [46]
  "", // [47]
  "0", // [48]
  "1", // [49]
  "2", // [50]
  "3", // [51]
  "4", // [52]
  "5", // [53]
  "6", // [54]
  "7", // [55]
  "8", // [56]
  "9", // [57]
  "COLON", // [58]
  "SEMICOLON", // [59]
  "LESS_THAN", // [60]
  "EQUALS", // [61]
  "GREATER_THAN", // [62]
  "QUESTION_MARK", // [63]
  "AT", // [64]
  "A", // [65]
  "B", // [66]
  "C", // [67]
  "D", // [68]
  "E", // [69]
  "F", // [70]
  "G", // [71]
  "H", // [72]
  "I", // [73]
  "J", // [74]
  "K", // [75]
  "L", // [76]
  "M", // [77]
  "N", // [78]
  "O", // [79]
  "P", // [80]
  "Q", // [81]
  "R", // [82]
  "S", // [83]
  "T", // [84]
  "U", // [85]
  "V", // [86]
  "W", // [87]
  "X", // [88]
  "Y", // [89]
  "Z", // [90]
  "OS_KEY", // [91] Windows Key (Windows) or Command Key (Mac)
  "", // [92]
  "CONTEXT_MENU", // [93]
  "", // [94]
  "SLEEP", // [95]
  "NUMPAD0", // [96]
  "NUMPAD1", // [97]
  "NUMPAD2", // [98]
  "NUMPAD3", // [99]
  "NUMPAD4", // [100]
  "NUMPAD5", // [101]
  "NUMPAD6", // [102]
  "NUMPAD7", // [103]
  "NUMPAD8", // [104]
  "NUMPAD9", // [105]
  "MULTIPLY", // [106]
  "ADD", // [107]
  "SEPARATOR", // [108]
  "SUBTRACT", // [109]
  "DECIMAL", // [110]
  "DIVIDE", // [111]
  "F1", // [112]
  "F2", // [113]
  "F3", // [114]
  "F4", // [115]
  "F5", // [116]
  "F6", // [117]
  "F7", // [118]
  "F8", // [119]
  "F9", // [120]
  "F10", // [121]
  "F11", // [122]
  "F12", // [123]
  "F13", // [124]
  "F14", // [125]
  "F15", // [126]
  "F16", // [127]
  "F17", // [128]
  "F18", // [129]
  "F19", // [130]
  "F20", // [131]
  "F21", // [132]
  "F22", // [133]
  "F23", // [134]
  "F24", // [135]
  "", // [136]
  "", // [137]
  "", // [138]
  "", // [139]
  "", // [140]
  "", // [141]
  "", // [142]
  "", // [143]
  "NUM_LOCK", // [144]
  "SCROLL_LOCK", // [145]
  "WIN_OEM_FJ_JISHO", // [146]
  "WIN_OEM_FJ_MASSHOU", // [147]
  "WIN_OEM_FJ_TOUROKU", // [148]
  "WIN_OEM_FJ_LOYA", // [149]
  "WIN_OEM_FJ_ROYA", // [150]
  "", // [151]
  "", // [152]
  "", // [153]
  "", // [154]
  "", // [155]
  "", // [156]
  "", // [157]
  "", // [158]
  "", // [159]
  "CIRCUMFLEX", // [160]
  "EXCLAMATION", // [161]
  "DOUBLE_QUOTE", // [162]
  "HASH", // [163]
  "DOLLAR", // [164]
  "PERCENT", // [165]
  "AMPERSAND", // [166]
  "UNDERSCORE", // [167]
  "OPEN_PAREN", // [168]
  "CLOSE_PAREN", // [169]
  "ASTERISK", // [170]
  "PLUS", // [171]
  "PIPE", // [172]
  "HYPHEN_MINUS", // [173]
  "OPEN_CURLY_BRACKET", // [174]
  "CLOSE_CURLY_BRACKET", // [175]
  "TILDE", // [176]
  "", // [177]
  "", // [178]
  "", // [179]
  "", // [180]
  "VOLUME_MUTE", // [181]
  "VOLUME_DOWN", // [182]
  "VOLUME_UP", // [183]
  "", // [184]
  "", // [185]
  "SEMICOLON", // [186]
  "EQUALS", // [187]
  "COMMA", // [188]
  "MINUS", // [189]
  "PERIOD", // [190]
  "SLASH", // [191]
  "BACK_QUOTE", // [192]
  "", // [193]
  "", // [194]
  "", // [195]
  "", // [196]
  "", // [197]
  "", // [198]
  "", // [199]
  "", // [200]
  "", // [201]
  "", // [202]
  "", // [203]
  "", // [204]
  "", // [205]
  "", // [206]
  "", // [207]
  "", // [208]
  "", // [209]
  "", // [210]
  "", // [211]
  "", // [212]
  "", // [213]
  "", // [214]
  "", // [215]
  "", // [216]
  "", // [217]
  "", // [218]
  "OPEN_BRACKET", // [219]
  "BACK_SLASH", // [220]
  "CLOSE_BRACKET", // [221]
  "QUOTE", // [222]
  "", // [223]
  "META", // [224]
  "ALTGR", // [225]
  "", // [226]
  "WIN_ICO_HELP", // [227]
  "WIN_ICO_00", // [228]
  "", // [229]
  "WIN_ICO_CLEAR", // [230]
  "", // [231]
  "", // [232]
  "WIN_OEM_RESET", // [233]
  "WIN_OEM_JUMP", // [234]
  "WIN_OEM_PA1", // [235]
  "WIN_OEM_PA2", // [236]
  "WIN_OEM_PA3", // [237]
  "WIN_OEM_WSCTRL", // [238]
  "WIN_OEM_CUSEL", // [239]
  "WIN_OEM_ATTN", // [240]
  "WIN_OEM_FINISH", // [241]
  "WIN_OEM_COPY", // [242]
  "WIN_OEM_AUTO", // [243]
  "WIN_OEM_ENLW", // [244]
  "WIN_OEM_BACKTAB", // [245]
  "ATTN", // [246]
  "CRSEL", // [247]
  "EXSEL", // [248]
  "EREOF", // [249]
  "PLAY", // [250]
  "ZOOM", // [251]
  "", // [252]
  "PA1", // [253]
  "WIN_OEM_CLEAR", // [254]
  "" // [255]
];
```

> **Note:** *The position of each value in the array above is important.* The `""` are placeholders for codes with unknown values.

Try the following code snippet using this static array lookup approach...

```js
var keyCodes = [];

$("#reset").click(function() {
  keyCodes = [];
  $("#in").val("");
  $("#key-codes").html("var keyCodes = [ ];");
  $("#key-names").html("var keyNames = [ ];");
});

$(document).keydown(function(e) {
  keyCodes.push(e.which);
  updateOutput();
});

function updateOutput() {
  var kC = "var keyCodes = [ ";
  var kN = "var keyNames = [ ";

  var len = keyCodes.length;

  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    kC += keyCodes[i];
    kN += "'"+keyboardMap[keyCodes[i]]+"'";
    if (i !== (len - 1)) {
      kC += ", ";
      kN += ", ";
    }
  }

  kC += " ];";
  kN += " ];";

  $("#key-codes").html(kC);
  $("#key-names").html(kN);
}



var keyboardMap = [
  "", // [0]
  "", // [1]
  "", // [2]
  "CANCEL", // [3]
  "", // [4]
  "", // [5]
  "HELP", // [6]
  "", // [7]
  "BACK_SPACE", // [8]
  "TAB", // [9]
  "", // [10]
  "", // [11]
  "CLEAR", // [12]
  "ENTER", // [13]
  "ENTER_SPECIAL", // [14]
  "", // [15]
  "SHIFT", // [16]
  "CONTROL", // [17]
  "ALT", // [18]
  "PAUSE", // [19]
  "CAPS_LOCK", // [20]
  "KANA", // [21]
  "EISU", // [22]
  "JUNJA", // [23]
  "FINAL", // [24]
  "HANJA", // [25]
  "", // [26]
  "ESCAPE", // [27]
  "CONVERT", // [28]
  "NONCONVERT", // [29]
  "ACCEPT", // [30]
  "MODECHANGE", // [31]
  "SPACE", // [32]
  "PAGE_UP", // [33]
  "PAGE_DOWN", // [34]
  "END", // [35]
  "HOME", // [36]
  "LEFT", // [37]
  "UP", // [38]
  "RIGHT", // [39]
  "DOWN", // [40]
  "SELECT", // [41]
  "PRINT", // [42]
  "EXECUTE", // [43]
  "PRINTSCREEN", // [44]
  "INSERT", // [45]
  "DELETE", // [46]
  "", // [47]
  "0", // [48]
  "1", // [49]
  "2", // [50]
  "3", // [51]
  "4", // [52]
  "5", // [53]
  "6", // [54]
  "7", // [55]
  "8", // [56]
  "9", // [57]
  "COLON", // [58]
  "SEMICOLON", // [59]
  "LESS_THAN", // [60]
  "EQUALS", // [61]
  "GREATER_THAN", // [62]
  "QUESTION_MARK", // [63]
  "AT", // [64]
  "A", // [65]
  "B", // [66]
  "C", // [67]
  "D", // [68]
  "E", // [69]
  "F", // [70]
  "G", // [71]
  "H", // [72]
  "I", // [73]
  "J", // [74]
  "K", // [75]
  "L", // [76]
  "M", // [77]
  "N", // [78]
  "O", // [79]
  "P", // [80]
  "Q", // [81]
  "R", // [82]
  "S", // [83]
  "T", // [84]
  "U", // [85]
  "V", // [86]
  "W", // [87]
  "X", // [88]
  "Y", // [89]
  "Z", // [90]
  "OS_KEY", // [91] Windows Key (Windows) or Command Key (Mac)
  "", // [92]
  "CONTEXT_MENU", // [93]
  "", // [94]
  "SLEEP", // [95]
  "NUMPAD0", // [96]
  "NUMPAD1", // [97]
  "NUMPAD2", // [98]
  "NUMPAD3", // [99]
  "NUMPAD4", // [100]
  "NUMPAD5", // [101]
  "NUMPAD6", // [102]
  "NUMPAD7", // [103]
  "NUMPAD8", // [104]
  "NUMPAD9", // [105]
  "MULTIPLY", // [106]
  "ADD", // [107]
  "SEPARATOR", // [108]
  "SUBTRACT", // [109]
  "DECIMAL", // [110]
  "DIVIDE", // [111]
  "F1", // [112]
  "F2", // [113]
  "F3", // [114]
  "F4", // [115]
  "F5", // [116]
  "F6", // [117]
  "F7", // [118]
  "F8", // [119]
  "F9", // [120]
  "F10", // [121]
  "F11", // [122]
  "F12", // [123]
  "F13", // [124]
  "F14", // [125]
  "F15", // [126]
  "F16", // [127]
  "F17", // [128]
  "F18", // [129]
  "F19", // [130]
  "F20", // [131]
  "F21", // [132]
  "F22", // [133]
  "F23", // [134]
  "F24", // [135]
  "", // [136]
  "", // [137]
  "", // [138]
  "", // [139]
  "", // [140]
  "", // [141]
  "", // [142]
  "", // [143]
  "NUM_LOCK", // [144]
  "SCROLL_LOCK", // [145]
  "WIN_OEM_FJ_JISHO", // [146]
  "WIN_OEM_FJ_MASSHOU", // [147]
  "WIN_OEM_FJ_TOUROKU", // [148]
  "WIN_OEM_FJ_LOYA", // [149]
  "WIN_OEM_FJ_ROYA", // [150]
  "", // [151]
  "", // [152]
  "", // [153]
  "", // [154]
  "", // [155]
  "", // [156]
  "", // [157]
  "", // [158]
  "", // [159]
  "CIRCUMFLEX", // [160]
  "EXCLAMATION", // [161]
  "DOUBLE_QUOTE", // [162]
  "HASH", // [163]
  "DOLLAR", // [164]
  "PERCENT", // [165]
  "AMPERSAND", // [166]
  "UNDERSCORE", // [167]
  "OPEN_PAREN", // [168]
  "CLOSE_PAREN", // [169]
  "ASTERISK", // [170]
  "PLUS", // [171]
  "PIPE", // [172]
  "HYPHEN_MINUS", // [173]
  "OPEN_CURLY_BRACKET", // [174]
  "CLOSE_CURLY_BRACKET", // [175]
  "TILDE", // [176]
  "", // [177]
  "", // [178]
  "", // [179]
  "", // [180]
  "VOLUME_MUTE", // [181]
  "VOLUME_DOWN", // [182]
  "VOLUME_UP", // [183]
  "", // [184]
  "", // [185]
  "SEMICOLON", // [186]
  "EQUALS", // [187]
  "COMMA", // [188]
  "MINUS", // [189]
  "PERIOD", // [190]
  "SLASH", // [191]
  "BACK_QUOTE", // [192]
  "", // [193]
  "", // [194]
  "", // [195]
  "", // [196]
  "", // [197]
  "", // [198]
  "", // [199]
  "", // [200]
  "", // [201]
  "", // [202]
  "", // [203]
  "", // [204]
  "", // [205]
  "", // [206]
  "", // [207]
  "", // [208]
  "", // [209]
  "", // [210]
  "", // [211]
  "", // [212]
  "", // [213]
  "", // [214]
  "", // [215]
  "", // [216]
  "", // [217]
  "", // [218]
  "OPEN_BRACKET", // [219]
  "BACK_SLASH", // [220]
  "CLOSE_BRACKET", // [221]
  "QUOTE", // [222]
  "", // [223]
  "META", // [224]
  "ALTGR", // [225]
  "", // [226]
  "WIN_ICO_HELP", // [227]
  "WIN_ICO_00", // [228]
  "", // [229]
  "WIN_ICO_CLEAR", // [230]
  "", // [231]
  "", // [232]
  "WIN_OEM_RESET", // [233]
  "WIN_OEM_JUMP", // [234]
  "WIN_OEM_PA1", // [235]
  "WIN_OEM_PA2", // [236]
  "WIN_OEM_PA3", // [237]
  "WIN_OEM_WSCTRL", // [238]
  "WIN_OEM_CUSEL", // [239]
  "WIN_OEM_ATTN", // [240]
  "WIN_OEM_FINISH", // [241]
  "WIN_OEM_COPY", // [242]
  "WIN_OEM_AUTO", // [243]
  "WIN_OEM_ENLW", // [244]
  "WIN_OEM_BACKTAB", // [245]
  "ATTN", // [246]
  "CRSEL", // [247]
  "EXSEL", // [248]
  "EREOF", // [249]
  "PLAY", // [250]
  "ZOOM", // [251]
  "", // [252]
  "PA1", // [253]
  "WIN_OEM_CLEAR", // [254]
  "" // [255]
];
```

```css
#key-codes,
#key-names {
  font-family: courier, serif;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="in" placeholder="Type here..." />
<button id="reset">Reset</button>
<br/>
<br/>
<div id="key-codes">var keyCodes = [ ];</div>
<div id="key-names">var keyNames = [ ];</div>
```

---

## Key codes worth noting

**Letters A-Z:** (65-90)

```
keyboardMap[65];  // A
...
keyboardMap[90];  // Z
```

**Digits 0-9:** (48-57)

```
keyboardMap[48];  // 0
...
keyboardMap[57];  // 9
```

**Number Pad 0-9:** (96-105)

```
keyboardMap[96];   // NUMPAD0
...
keyboardMap[105];  // NUMPAD9
```

**Arrow Keys:** (37-40)

```
keyboardMap[37];  // LEFT
keyboardMap[38];  // UP
keyboardMap[39];  // RIGHT
keyboardMap[40];  // DOWN
```

**Tab Key:** (9)

```
keyboardMap[9];  // TAB
```

**Enter Key:** (13)

```
keyboardMap[13];  // ENTER
```

**Spacebar Key:** (32)

```
keyboardMap[32];  // SPACE
```

**OS Specific Key** (91) *Windows Key (Windows) or Command Key (Mac)*

```
keyboardMap[91];  // OS_KEY
```

**Alt Key:** (18)

```
keyboardMap[18];  // ALT
```

**Control Key:** (17)

```
keyboardMap[17];  // CONTROL
```

**Shift Key:** (16)

```
keyboardMap[16];  // SHIFT
```

**Caps Lock Key:** (20)

```
keyboardMap[20];  // CAPS_LOCK
```

Comment: not working for special chars, if enter keys with shift key, any solution?

Answer (score 19):

Just an important note: the accepted answer above will not work correctly for keyCode >= 144, i.e. period, comma, dash, etc. For those you should use a more general algorithm:

```
let chrCode = keyCode - 48 * Math.floor(keyCode / 48);
let chr = String.fromCharCode((96 <= keyCode) ? chrCode: keyCode);
```

If you're curious as to why, this is apparently necessary because of the behavior of the built-in JS function `String.fromCharCode()`. For values of `keyCode <= 96` it seems to map using the function:

`chrCode = keyCode - 48 * Math.floor(keyCode / 48)`

For values of `keyCode > 96` it seems to map using the function:

`chrCode = keyCode`

If this seems like odd behavior then well..I agree. Sadly enough, it would be very far from the weirdest thing I've seen in the JS core.

```js
document.onkeydown = function(e) {
    let keyCode = e.keyCode;
    let chrCode = keyCode - 48 * Math.floor(keyCode / 48);
    let chr = String.fromCharCode((96 <= keyCode) ? chrCode: keyCode);
    console.log(chr);
};
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Focus and Type"/>
```

Comment: You're going to confuse people by using `let` in an answer to a question from 2009. :-)

Comment: If someone discovers ES6 by looking up `let` then I did them a favor ;-)

Comment: @galarant Can you please explain why/how this works?

Comment: @IzharAazmi added explanation. Hope it helps!

Comment: @DavidMurdoch but its not 2009 anymore :)

Comment: This does not work fully because it doesn't take into account holding the shift key, but it is a start at least.

Comment: It also doesn't work correctly for the number keys on an numeric keypad (the grid of keys on the right of extended keyboards).

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the read-only property [`key`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key). It also respects special keys like <kbd>shift</kbd> etc. and is supported by IE9.

When a non-printable or special character is pressed, the value will be on of the defined [key values](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key/Key_Values) like `'Shift'` or `'Multiply'`.

- Keyboard     `event.key`
- <kbd>X</kbd>             -> `'x'`
- <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>  -> `'X'`
- <kbd>F5</kbd>            -> `'F5'`

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming this is for a game or for a fast-responding type of application hence the use of KEYDOWN than KEYPRESS.

**Edit**:
Dang! I stand corrected (thank you Crescent Fresh and David): JQuery (or even rather the underlying DOM hosts) do *not* expose the detail of the WM_KEYDOWN and of other events.  Rather they pre-digest this data and, in the case of keyDown even in JQuery, we get:

- [event.keyCode](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Event.keyCode)   for non-character keys
- [event.charCode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.charCode)  for character keys

Note that these properties are the UniCode values.
Note, I wasn't able to find an authorititative reference to that in JQuery docs, but many reputable examples on the net refer to these two properties.

The following code, adapted from some java (not javascript) of mine, is therefore totally wrong...

The following will give you the "interesting" parts of the keycode:

```
  value = e.KeyCode;
  repeatCount = value & 0xFF;
  scanCode = (value >> 16) & 0xFF;  // note we take the "extended bit" deal w/ it later.
  wasDown = ((value & 0x4000) != 0);  // indicate key was readily down (auto-repeat)
  if (scanCode > 127)
      // deal with extended
  else
      // "regular" character
```

Comment: hm, no go, scanCode always results in 0.  And e.KeyCode should be e.keyCode (KeyCode is undefined).

Comment: Hey now...Hello, wait...wha?? We talkin JScript here or something?

Comment: @David M.  My bad, maybe JQuery "pre-digests" these code parts for us.  I'm looking into it now.

Comment: @mjv: where did you get this code? Has it ever worked for you? AFAIK no DOM implementation encodes all that info into the event object (`keydown` or not).

Comment: @Crescent: I adapted it quickly and naively from some java code of mine, way old at that...  Anyway, you are totally right: none of the DOM hosts hand-out any such raw events, even for the keyboard.  I fixed my prose accordingly; still looking for an authoritative doc on the subject from JQuery.com

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I came across it today searching for a pre-packaged solution to this problem, and found nothing that really met my needs.

Here is a solution (English only) that correctly supports Upper Case (shifted), Lower Case, punctuation, number keypad, etc.

It also allows for simple and straight-forward identification of - and reaction to - non-printable keys, like ESC, Arrows, Function keys, etc.

https://jsfiddle.net/5hhu896g/1/

```
keyboardCharMap and keyboardNameMap are the key to making this work
```

Thanks to DaveAlger for saving me some typing - and much discovery! - by providing the Named Key Array.

Comment: Your fiddle is most excellent! Thanks for sharing. It works excellently. I am using it to implement a Sublime-style multi-cursor edit for form fields with items having the same values

Answer (score 0):

I recently wrote a module called [keysight](https://github.com/fresheneesz/keysight) that translates `keypress`, `keydown`, and `keyup` events into characters and keys respectively.

Example:

```
 element.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
    var character = keysight(event).char
 })
```

Comment: does it supports keys like ñ?

Comment: @ArnoldRoa I just pushed something that hopefully will support characters like that. I don't have a keyboard with accented characters, so would you mind testing?

Answer (score 0):

For those of you who came here looking for the actual Unicode character values for a keycode, like I did, here is a function for that. For instance, given the right arrow unicode keycode this will output the visible string `\u001B\u005B\u0043`

```
function toUnicode(theString) {
    var unicodeString = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < theString.length; i++) {
        var theUnicode = theString.charCodeAt(i).toString(16).toUpperCase();
        while (theUnicode.length < 4) {
            theUnicode = '0' + theUnicode;
        }
        theUnicode = '\\u' + theUnicode;
        unicodeString += theUnicode;
    }
    return unicodeString;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Refer this link
[Get Keycode from key press and char value for any key code](http://jsfiddle.net/YKeye/)

```
$('input#inp').keyup(function(e){
   $(this).val(String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode)); 
   $('div#output').html('Keycode : ' + e.keyCode);  
});
```

Comment: This is incorrect! As it doesn't take into account current language enabled on user's keyboard. For example, I enter 'ф', but it gives 'a'...

Comment: this is incorrect, text will change according to keyboard layot