# How to find out what character key is pressed?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, keypress

I would like to find out what character key is pressed in a cross-browser compatible way in pure Javascript.

Comment: Aren't all these answers for the question "what key _was_ pressed?"  What if, as it's executing, javascript code wants to know if a key on the keyboard is currently held down?

Comment: `event.key` will directly give you the pressed char

Answer (score 191, accepted):

"Clear" JavaScript:

```js
function myKeyPress(e){
  var keynum;

  if(window.event) { // IE                  
    keynum = e.keyCode;
  } else if(e.which){ // Netscape/Firefox/Opera                 
    keynum = e.which;
  }

  alert(String.fromCharCode(keynum));
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onkeypress="return myKeyPress(event)" />
```

JQuery:

```js
$("input").keypress(function(event){
  alert(String.fromCharCode(event.which)); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input/>
```

Comment: this works ok for alphabetic chars, but what about dots/brakets and other typogtaphic symbols?

Comment: @VoVaVc: It works for those too. The crucial thing is using the `keypress` event, which gives you a character code, rather than `keyup` or `keydown` which give you a key code.

Comment: `e.which` is deprecated. Use `e.key` instead, as in `if(e.key == 'z')`

Comment: @aljgom, `e.key` still doesn't have full browser support.

Comment: Doesn't work for symbols that you have to press shift to make, like !

Comment: @AndyMercer key is now supported by all major browsers: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key#Browser_compatibility

Comment: The keypress event seems to be deprecated https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-keypress

Comment: the `keyCode` for `ArrowLeft` is 37, which is `%` symbol. So this conversion doesn't seem to be fully reliable

Answer (score 52):

More recent and much cleaner: use `event.key`. No more arbitrary number codes!

> NOTE: The old properties (`.keyCode` and `.which`) are Deprecated.

```
node.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
    const key = event.key; // "a", "1", "Shift", etc.
});
```

If you want to make sure only single characters are entered, check `key.length === 1`, or that it is one of the characters you expect.

[Mozilla Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key)

[Supported Browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=keyboardevent-key)

Comment: Is this for node.js?

Comment: No, node just means any DOM element. If you had Node.js connecting to a UI, I suppose it would work

Comment: keydown for some mobile device doesn't work  it return undefine

Answer (score 43):

There are a million duplicates of this question on here, but here goes again anyway:

```
document.onkeypress = function(evt) {
    evt = evt || window.event;
    var charCode = evt.keyCode || evt.which;
    var charStr = String.fromCharCode(charCode);
    alert(charStr);
};
```

The best reference on key events I've seen is http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html.

Answer (score 17):

Copy-paste this into your address-bar:

```
data:text/html,<body style=font:12vw' onkeyup="this.innerHTML=['key','keyCode','code'].map(k=>k+': '+event[k]).join`<br>`">Press a key
```

This is just 134 bytes of code to produce the `key`, `keyCode`, and `code` of the key you've just pressed. You can also save this as a bookmark so you can run it anytime.

```html
<body style=font:8vw'
  onkeyup="this.innerHTML=['key','keyCode','code'].map(k=>k+': '+event[k]).join`<br>`"
  >Press a key
```

This works in "Run code snippet" as well.

Comment: Here's another similar site but with a few additional options: https://keyjs.dev

Comment: on chrome, xfce, italian keyboard, spanish layout, pressing "<" returns "/", which is the key which is there in english keyboard. Why?!? some chrome versions ago it was not that!

Answer (score 3):

Use this one:

```
function onKeyPress(evt){
  evt = (evt) ? evt : (window.event) ? event : null;
  if (evt)
  {
    var charCode = (evt.charCode) ? evt.charCode :((evt.keyCode) ? evt.keyCode :((evt.which) ? evt.which : 0));
    if (charCode == 13) 
        alert('User pressed Enter');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
**check this out** 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).keypress(function(e)
        {

            var keynum;
            if(window.event)
            { // IE                 
                keynum = e.keyCode;
            }
                else if(e.which)
                    { 
                    // Netscape/Firefox/Opera                   
                    keynum = e.which;
                    }
                    alert(String.fromCharCode(keynum));
                    var unicode=e.keyCode? e.keyCode : e.charCode;
                    alert(unicode);
        });
});  

</script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="text"></input>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Isn't this a near-exact duplicate of @Coyod's 2009 answer?

Answer (score 2):

Detecting Keyboard press in JavaScript:

```
document.addEventListener(
  "keydown",
  function(event) {
    console.log(event.key);
  },
);
```

Answer (score 1):

One of my favorite libraries to do this in a sophisticated way is [Mousetrap](https://craig.is/killing/mice).

It comes stocked with a variety of plugins, one of which is the `record` plugin which can identify a sequence of keys pressed.

Example:

```
<script>
    function recordSequence() {
        Mousetrap.record(function(sequence) {
            // sequence is an array like ['ctrl+k', 'c']
            alert('You pressed: ' + sequence.join(' '));
        });
    }
</script>


<button onclick="recordSequence()">Record</button>
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Mousetrap.record is not a function
    at recordSequence (****.html:12)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (****.html:20)

Answer (score 0):

BH

If you're trying to get the value in client side JavaScript via the DOM, then a reliable alternative I've found is to make an invisible `<input>` element, with an absolute position and (almost) no width, positioned underneath wherever you're typing, then when the user clicks or sets focus to whatever they're supposed to type on, call the `focus()` function on the input, and use the result from the `oninput` event to get the string entered into the input, and then get the first character from that string, or loop through it

(And make some exceptions for shift keys etc)

Then at the end of every event simply reset the `value` of the input to an empty string

Comment: You should be able to add a `keydown` listener to `document` without needing to create an extra input element. This answer adds very little to the existing ones.

Comment: @Matthias and what is the cross browser, reliable way to get the Unicode character pressed by the user with any other method than this one? The .key property isn't supported on many mobile devices. Even charCode from keypress is no longer supported. Even keyCode from keydown etc is no longer supported, and only dealt with the key itself, not the Unicode char.

Answer (score -2):

```
document.onkeypress = function(event){
    alert(event.key)
}
```

Comment: two negative votes but now explaination why it is voted negative. I think it help when you comment what is the problem with this answer. thanks

Comment: easy to vote, I guess you bettter try this snippet on your own :)
title is pretty common by the way