# How to know pressed key using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, onkeypress

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [js: how to find out what character key is pressed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846599/js-how-to-find-out-what-character-key-is-pressed)

I want to know how to make an event on key pressing and to specify which key is pressed using Javascript only.

Comment: See this question for your answer.


  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846599/js-how-to-find-out-what-character-key-is-pressed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myKeyPress(e){

        var keynum;

        if(window.event){ // IE                 
            keynum = e.keyCode;
        }else
            if(e.which){ // Netscape/Firefox/Opera                  
                keynum = e.which;
             }
        alert(String.fromCharCode(keynum));
    }
   </script>


 <form>
  <input type="text" onkeypress="return myKeyPress(event)" />
 </form>
```

Referred from [How to find out what character key is pressed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846599/js-how-to-find-out-what-character-key-is-pressed)