# Every time when i pressed the enter key then it should alert some thing

Tags: javascript

If i write some thing in input field and then i pressed enter then it should alert the specific value.Here is the code. please help me

```
<html>
<input type="text" class="searchfld" id='input' onchange="gotothatpost(this.value)"onkeyup="ajxsrch(this.value,getAscii())">
</html>
<script>
function ajxsrch(str,asci)
{
  if(asci==13)
   {
    alert("You pressed enter");
   }
  else
   {
    do something;
   }
}
</script>
```

Comment: where is the rest of your code?

Comment: @derstrom8 Agreed.  The code, as shown, will never get called.  `getAscii()` will be undefined and throw an exception, so `ajxsrch` will never get called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you want us to define the `getAscii()` function for you. Using code partially modified from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1846704/391161), the following example should work.

```
<html>
<input type="text" class="searchfld" id='input'  onkeyup='ajxsrch(this.value, getAscii(event))'>
<script>
function getAscii(e) {
    if (window.event){ // IE                    
       return e.keyCode;
    }else {
         // Netscape/Firefox/Opera                  
        return e.which;
    }
}
function ajxsrch(str,asci)
{
  if(asci==13)
   {
    alert("You pressed enter");
   }
}
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: I was typing up my own getAscii function but you beat me to it! +1

Comment: @derstrom8, I just modified the one I found on another answer. :)