# Simple way to compare a key pressed to a character in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, keydown, keyevent, key-events

You can get the `keyCode` of a key pressed in jQuery:

```
$('#myField').keydown(function(event) {
    console.log(event.which);
});
```

How do I compare that to a letter? I could, of course, find out the keyCode of that letter, but I don't know ahead of time what that letter is. So I could convert every letter to a keyCode and look that up in an object. I have to imagine there's an easier way for this common situation?

Does `myLetter.charCodeAt(0)` always give me the same number as `event.which` for the same letter?

Comment: Same question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846599/how-to-find-out-what-character-key-is-pressed

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `String.fromCharCode` to convert a Unicode number into a character:

```
 String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode)
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to use this:

```
String.fromCharCode();
```

use it here:

```
$('#myField').keydown(function(e) {
    var kc = e.which || e.keyCode;
    console.log(String.fromCharCode(kc).toUpperCase() == "A"); // should log true if
    // "A" character is pressed.
});
```