# Determining which key was pressed

Tags: javascript

This way works but it strikes me as working too hard.

**Question**: How do you determine which key has been pressed?

```
;(function() {
    var Variables = {}
    Variables.slash = false
    $('[name=myName]').keypress(keypress)
    function keypress(myEvent) {
        if (myEvent.which === 47) {
            Variables.slash = true
        }
    }
    $('[name=myName]').keyup(keyup)
    function keyup(myEvent) {
        if (Variables.slash) {
           Variables.slash = false

        }
    }
})()
```

Comment: You would like to know if the slash got pressed? Or whats the meaning ob the Variables-object and the slash property?

Comment: Yes, this snippet looks like it's more complicated than it needs to be. I just need to know when the slash has been pressed.

Answer (score 1):

It can be simplified, by following steps:

- You need to find out the ASCII code of the key pressed (https://api.jquery.com/event.which/)
- Now just use a ASCII reference table and find out which char was pressed.

Answer (score 1):

The `myEvent` variable will contain the **ASCII** code of the key that have been pressed.
The ASCII code of *slash* is 47. ([See here](http://www.asciitable.com/))

Answer (score 0):

From a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846599/how-to-find-out-what-character-key-is-pressed):

"Clear" JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function myKeyPress(e){

            var keynum;

            if(window.event){ // IE                 
                keynum = e.keyCode;
            }
            else if(e.which){ // Netscape/Firefox/Opera                 
                keynum = e.which;
            }

            alert(String.fromCharCode(keynum));
        }
</script>


<form>
    <input type="text" onkeypress="return myKeyPress(event)" />
</form>
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).keypress(function(event){
    alert(String.fromCharCode(event.which)); 
 })
```