# How To Tell If The W Key's Pressed

Tags: javascript, key

So I'm making a game and I want to be able to add controls for a character. So I want the game to be able to detect if the user presses the key W. Something like this

```
    if(W is pressed){
     Do something
    }
```

Comment: Look up how to handle key press events.

Comment: This could be useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846599/how-to-find-out-what-character-key-is-pressed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an EventListener for `keydown` and check the `event` :

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e){
   if(e.key === 'w')
   console.log('hei w')
})
```

Comment: Thanks, worked perfectly!

Comment: @TheGamerKing glad to know that helped..

Answer (score 1):

The following code should do it for you

```js
function keyW(e) {
    if(e.keyCode === 87){
       console.log('w');
    };
}
document.onkeydown = keyW;
```

Comment: This worked, but I chose someone else's answer too, thanks =).

Answer (score 1):

If you already capture the keypress, you can just convert the event key number to a character and then proceed with your condition as following:

```
if ( String.fromCharCode(keynum) == 'W' ) {
    // Processing
}
```

If you're not capturing the event yet, just do as following:

```
document.onkeypress = function(e) {
    var keynum = e.which;
    if ( String.fromCharCode(keynum) == 'W' ) {
        // Processing
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked but I chose maioman's answer instead, sorry

Answer (score -1):

You can use onkeypress event for this.

The onkeypress event occurs when the user presses a key (on the keyboard).

**In HTML:**

```
<element onkeypress="myScript">
```

**In JavaScript:**

```
object.onkeypress=function(){myScript};
```

**In JavaScript, using the addEventListener() method:**

```
object.addEventListener("keypress", myScript);
```

I took this information from http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeypress.asp
You can also search internet for more information about events in javascript language.
Good Luck!

Comment: He was only concerned with the user pressing 'w'.

Comment: It's fine, though that is true, sorry Asim