# Only allowing 0-9 numbers in input type="number" (exlude eE.+- etc..)

Tags: javascript, html

I am having a bit of a hard time figuring out how to only allow user to input numbers 0-9 in an `<input type="number" />` as it also allwos other things like `eE.+ -` etc..

Looked at regex solutions here on stack overflow and each one seems to have an issue i.e. if there are no numbers in an input you can type in any of unwanted characters, if you typed in a number you can't delete it completely as there needs to be at least 1 digit.

using keycodes introduces an issue as `event.target.value` is not avaliable on key events, it seems to only be available in `onchange`, however in this case `e.which` is not avaliable to check key pressed.

Comment: What are your exact requirements? You would like to have an input that allows one or more numeric characters (but not special characters)?

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean you only want users to be able to enter digits 0-9?

```js
var input = document.getElementById("only-digits");
input.onkeydown = function(e) {
  if (48 > e.which || e.which > 57)
    if (e.key.length === 1)
      e.preventDefault();
};
```

```html
<input type="number" id="only-digits">
```

I'm making sure that [the key the user presses](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1846704/3310334) is only a 0, 1, 2, ... 9 character using the range of their [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) values.

If the key they pressed was outside of that range, then I make sure it is a word character and then I prevent it from being entered into the text field.

Comment: This prevents the user from deleting numbers, pressing return or tabbing to another input.

Comment: Not my downvote but I still can't tab away from the input or use the backspace key to delete characters (Chrome 54)

Comment: Now it allows multiple `.` characters.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the regex attribute on the html input field:

```
<input pattern="[0-9]*">
```

this allows only for 0-9 characters, zero or multiple times

```
<input pattern="[0-9]+">
```

this allows only for 0-9 characters, 1 or multiple times

## update

it doesn't work with type="number" though, if you want it to work with this, you need to use javascript. See the other answers for this.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/4gpf5vv3/ still able to enter all of those unwanted values :/

Comment: [`pattern` only works on `text`, `search`, `tel`, `url`, `email`, or `password`.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-pattern)

Comment: @Ilja but you can't submit it, it tests on submit: https://jsfiddle.net/4gpf5vv3/1/

Comment: @JoelHarkes Try entering `1e6` in your jsfiddle.

Comment: Thats interesting because `.` is not allowed, try this: https://jsfiddle.net/4gpf5vv3/2/

Comment: This is only a validation thing, it doesn't stop the letters from actually being entered.

Comment: jup, then you should use javascript, but everything can be disabled by the user, you should always validate in the backend!

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent user when he/she enters any character other than Number

See the below code
HTML

```
<input type=number class="numberOnlyInput" oncopy="return false" onpaste="return false" ondrag="return false">
```

JQuery

```
$(document).on('keypress','.numberOnlyInput',function(e){
  if(!(e.keyCode >=48 && e.keyCode <=57) ){
        e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

You can see the demo here: 
https://jsfiddle.net/cnosh74e/