# How can I detect that the user typed a specific character ("@") into a textfield?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to detect any "@"-inputs into a textfield but have no idea how to get that information as two keys have to be pressed to write the @-sign.

And I don't even know if these keys are the same in every country so basically I'm asking if there's a way to check the last typed character (without checking the keys).

Comment: Do you really need to detect the *last typed character*, or would it be fine to find `@` anywhere in the field?

Comment: Yes, as a menu has to popup everytime, the user types the @-sign.

Comment: I know but then I wouldn't handle the case when the user moves the cursor "inwards" and types @.

Comment: create a "keyup" or "keydown" event listener for the input field using jQuery, then wrap the function that the event listener calls with a debounce function that would check the entry of the field for the '@' using a simple regex expression.

Comment: Hm, I see. So no that wouldn't solve your problem then

Comment: I could save the number of occurence of the @ sign in a variable and open the menu everytime the count gows up but I think this would be a bit overkill as with every change on the textfield the whole text had to be scanned (max. 650 chars), I don't know if this is a performance issue.

Comment: Check out this question, I think it has you covered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846599/how-to-find-out-what-character-key-is-pressed. Or the answer below works...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty simple:

```js
const input = document.getElementById('input');

input.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  if (e.key === '@') alert('@ typed!');
})
```

```html
<input type="text" id='input'>
```

The typed character is stored inside `event.key` property passed to the event handler.

Comment: This was the answer I was waiting for :D Thank you