# W3Schools game tutorial trouble

Tags: javascript, html

So im just starting out learning Javascript, and I'm following the game tutorial in https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/game_obstacles.asp 
This is the point i've gotten stuck at. If you check out the code in the example, they've added a working obstacle, but the game won't work with the keyboard. (only with buttons added to the site)
I want to be able to steer the character with my keyboard, and have a working obstacle, that will stop the game when the two touch.

I would appreciate any help i could get from this. (the code i use is in the example in the link above)

Comment: so basically, most of your question is "how do i listen for keypresses in Javascript"?

Answer (score 0):

you will need a little bit more than in the shown example.

Here is a reference with an example for key pressed events [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1846704/3652823)

Short excerpt:

> "Clear" JavaScript:
>
> ```
> <script type="text/javascript">
>   function myKeyPress(e){
>     var keynum;
>
>     if(window.event) { // IE                    
>       keynum = e.keyCode;
>     } else if(e.which){ // Netscape/Firefox/Opera                   
>       keynum = e.which;
>     }
>
>     alert(String.fromCharCode(keynum));
>   }
> </script>
>
> <form>
>   <input type="text" onkeypress="return myKeyPress(event)" />
> </form>
> ```

You could also solve it in jquery

> JQuery:
>
> ```
> $(document).keypress(function(event){
>   alert(String.fromCharCode(event.which)); 
> });
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Add this in you code to move the block.

```
window.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
console.log(event);
if(event.keyCode === 38){
    console.log(event);
    myGamePiece.speedY -= 1; 
} else if (event.keyCode === 37){
    myGamePiece.speedX = -1; 
} else if (event.keyCode === 39){
    myGamePiece.speedX = 1; 
} else if (event.keyCode === 40){
    myGamePiece.speedY = 1; 
}
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Do following changes:

Add `onkeypress` event in `body` element i.e. `<body onkeypress="myFunction(event)" onload="startGame()" >`.

Define `myFunction` function as following:

```
function myFunction(event)
{
    switch(event.which || event.keyCode)
    {
    case 117: //Up 'U'
        moveup();
        break;
    case 106: //Down 'J'
        movedown();
        break;
    case 104: //Left 'H'
        moveleft();
        break;
    case 107: //Right 'K'
        moveright();
        break;
    }
}
```

You can get complete working code [here](https://ideone.com/MpzDoy). You can copy the complete code and run it locally.