# How display keypress in div

Tags: javascript, html

How can I display keycode in html div using function `event` and `document.onkeydown`. I need solution working on IE

Comment: yeah not found exactly my solution on older version of IE I tryed change this code but not working

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846599/how-to-find-out-what-character-key-is-pressed

Comment: cool, so you have done some research, from next time onwards, please add it along with your question. Questions without research efforts are not very welcomed here in SO

Comment: Hi worker555, welcome to SO. When asking questions, please refer to the [How-To-Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide so that we are able to answer your questions as precisely and accordingly to meet your question's requirements. @KrishnaPrashatt No need to be rude toward new contributors.

Answer (score 1):

For example this way:

```js
var outputDiv = document.querySelector('#output');

function onKeyDown (e) {
  outputDiv.innerHTML = e.which || e.keyCode;
}

document.onkeydown = onKeyDown;

// modern solution: document.addEventListener('keydown', onKeyDown);
```

```css
#output {
 padding: 10px;
 background: #efefef;
}
```

```html
<div id="output">Press a key</div>
```