# Is there any way to write some text in an input tag only by triggering keyboard events?

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dom-events, keyboard-events

I want to write some text in an input tag only by triggering keyboard events by programming.

I don't want to using something like

```
elem.value = 'some random text'
```

I really need to simulate keyboard to write code in this input tag.
pure Javascript is my goal, but if there is a good jQuery way, I will appreciate that too!

Answer (score 0):

not sure if you're looking for the infinite monkey?

```
function randChar() { //generate a random character - all lower case for simplicity
  var chars = " abcdefghijklmnopqurstuvwxyz";
  return chars.substr(Math.floor(Math.random() * 27), 1);
}
```

(not my code)

https://jsfiddle.net/concannon/d67b6y7k/

Comment: actually I m not looking for a way to randomize  picking a char. my goal is to trigger spasebar key on my code and write an " "  in text bar. but only by triggering keyup, keydown or keypress events in my js code.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key

Maybe listen to the body and then update the input.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846599/how-to-find-out-what-character-key-is-pressed

Comment: Do you want separate text's by pressing space ?