# Pressing the Z key to redirect isn't working

Tags: javascript, html

```
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script>
   

 var keyPressed = event.originalEvent.code;
                  if(keyPressed == 'KeyZ'){
                      location.replace("https://classroom.google.com");
                  }
        </script>
```

When clicking the Z key, nothing happens, however when I try it on a different project. The link is avackgames.xyz

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find out what character key is pressed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846599/how-to-find-out-what-character-key-is-pressed)

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you should use the 'keydown' event listener.

For more information please visit this website.... ([Click here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keydown_event))

This is the JavaScript code you should add to your HTML file code.
I hope it's clear and helpful, Thanks!.

```html
<script>
    //Create event listener for 'keydown'
    window.addEventListener('keydown', KeyPressed)
        //Create a function with 'event' parameter
    function KeyPressed(event) {
        //Checking if Z key pressed, For your information, the code '90' is for the Z key.
        if (event.keyCode == 90) {
            //To be sure that the 'Z' key was pressed, let's show an alert message.
            alert('Yeeess, you clicked Z key!')
        }
    }
</script>
```