# How to convert keycode to character using javascript

Tags: javascript, variables, keycode

How to convert keycode to character using javascript

```
var key_code = 65;
```

result should be

```
character = "a";
```

Comment: Worth remembering that [charCode sniffing is bad for your health](http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html) (and by health, I think I mean sanity). [See also here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5829387/1028230). Getting better since this question was asked, but still a nontrivial pain.

Comment: @ruffin  This is the best answer!

Answer (score 134, accepted):

[`String.fromCharCode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode) is what you want:

> The fromCharCode() method converts Unicode values to characters.
>
> ### Syntax
>
> ```
> String.fromCharCode(n1, n2, ..., nX)
> ```

Comment: Notice that String.fromCharCode(65) == 'A', to get 'a' a call to .toLowerCase() is needed.

Comment: Only if you've got the "key code" from a `keypress` event. In `keyup` and `keydown` events, the `keyCode` property has nothing to do with characters.

Comment: keyCode property from keydown event is the right combination to use with String.fromCharCode().  It works for me not the charCode.

Comment: @Arrix: yes, so how do you know if you need to call toLowerCase()?  You can't just look at event.shiftKey, because this will fail for keys like "!"

Comment: @Michael, I would suggest to always use .toLowerCase() if searching for specific letter (as in the example String.fromCharCode(65) == 'a'). There is no error thrown when trying to convert a lower case letter to lower case.

Comment: Readers beware: this approach completely fails if you're working with function keys (ie. 'F12'). The best approach I found is to just give in and use `event.key` instead of `event.keyCode` (and add a special case for each keyboard layout you need to support).  It's less robust but that's JS for you.

Answer (score 12):

As seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5829387/996795):

```
String.fromCharCode((96 <= key && key <= 105) ? key-48 : key)
```

Comment: Could you elaborate what this code does or checks?

Comment: This code maps Windows numpad keycodes for numpad 0 to numpad 9 (96 through 105) to the character codes 48 through 57, allowing the method to convert them back to their underlying values "0" to "9". This has no effect on Mac, as the numpad numbers already map to 48 to 57.