# Javascript numberpad keycode parsing

Tags: javascript, keycode

I am attempting to parse keydown events from the numberpad with the following:

```
$('#myDiv').keydown(function(e) {
  val = String.fromCharCode(e.which)
});
```

The problem is that keypad `0-9` return keyCodes of `96-105` which, according to `fromCharCode()` are the lower case letters `a-i`.  How do I get keydown events of the numberpad to resolve to the appropriate number?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You don't: you use the `keypress` event. The `keypress` event is the only event that will give you reliable information about typed characters. Your existing code will work if you simply change `keydown` to `keypress`.

Comment: Suppose I both want real characters from the keypad, and also want to capture and stop the Enter key, to prevent a form submit? Stopping keypress appears to still submit.

Comment: I can't express how thankful I am for this answer. This was my salvation trying to catch all the different possible cases with shift, alt, numpad and mobile keyboards. `keypress` makes it easy as cake!

Answer (score 9):

The `which` value passed to `keydown` is not a character code; it's a key code (and the codes vary from browser/OS to browser/OS). You can map it to a character using [the tables on this page](http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html), but to say that this stuff is a bit...awkward...would be to understate the case. :-)

Otherwise, your best bet is to wait for the `keypress` event, which will have the character code (if relevant) rather than a key code.

Example: [Live copy](http://jsbin.com/itejos) | [Live source](http://jsbin.com/itejos/edit)

```
jQuery(function($) {

  $("#theField")
    .keydown(function(event) {
      showKey("keydown", event.which);
    })
    .keypress(function(event) {
      showKey("keypress", event.which);
    })
    .focus();

  function showKey(eventName, which) {
    display(eventName +
            ": " + which + " (" +
            String.fromCharCode(which) + ")");
  }

  function display(msg) {
    $("<p>").html(msg).appendTo(document.body);
  }
});
```

Using this HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="theField">
```

Answer (score 4):

The answers here are now outdated because [KeyboardEvent.which](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/which), [KeyboardEvent.keyCode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode) and [KeyboardEvent.charCode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/charCode) are all deprecated.

The proper way for the latest versions of Firefox, Chrome, IE/Edge and Safari to obtain the character key is to use [KeyboardEvent.key](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key) and it should work with any key event, not just `keypress`.

[KeyboardEvent.key Browser Compatibility](http://caniuse.com/#feat=keyboardevent-key)

```js
document.
  querySelector('input').
  addEventListener('keydown', event => console.log(event.key));
```

```html
<input placeholder="Start typing...">
```

---

If you still need to obtain the character code, you should use the [KeyboardEvent.code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/code) property.

[KeyboardEvent.code Browser Compatibility](http://caniuse.com/#feat=keyboardevent-code)

```js
document.
  querySelector('input').
  addEventListener('keydown', event => console.log(event.code));
```

```html
<input placeholder="Start typing...">
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to do this with keydown, if keypress is not workable due to event canceling needs, etc. Use an if() statement with this test:

```
parseInt(event.keyIdentifier.substring(2),16) > 47 && parseInt(event.keyIdentifier.substring(2),16) < 58
```

OR, with jQuery events:

```
parseInt(event.originalEvent.keyIdentifier.substring(2),16) > 47 && parseInt(event.originalEvent.keyIdentifier.substring(2),16) < 58
```

These examples assume "event" is the keydown event. keyIdentifier is a hexidecimal number that represents the unicode value for the related char. Using keyIdentifier, numbers from the numberpad / keypad AND the numbers above your QWERTY keyboard will all have the same values, 48 - 57 (U+0030 - U+0039), even with the keyDown event.

Unicode values in the browsers will look like U+0030 or U+002F. Parse this string to only get the hexidecimal value, then use parseInt() with a radix of 16 to convert it to base-10.

Answer (score 0):

you can use keydown and detect numpad keys. I did it using following code. Subtract 48 from numpad keys before interpreting the key

```
function navigate(e) {
        var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
        if (keyCode >= 96 && keyCode <= 105) {
            // Numpad keys
            keyCode -= 48;
        }  
        var txtVal = String.fromCharCode(keyCode);
```