# keypress event. "*" seen as "j"

Tags: javascript, keypress, onkeypress

i tried to create a javascript event that detects when the * key is pressed.
code:

```
 function asterisk(e) {
     var evtobj = window.event ? event : e //distinguish between IE's explicit event object (window.event) and Firefox's implicit.
     var unicode = evtobj.charCode ? evtobj.charCode : evtobj.keyCode
     var actualkey = String.fromCharCode(unicode)
     alert(actualkey);
     if ((actualkey == "8" && evtobj.shiftKey) || actualkey == "*") {
         alert("banana");
         var tbbar = document.getElementById("tbBarcode");
         var tbam = document.getElementById("tbAmount");
         tbam.value = tbbar.value;
         tbbar.value = "";
         tbbar.focus();

     }
 }
```

when i press the * key on the number pad (the right side of the keyboard, not the shift+8 one) the alert says "j" insted of "*"
why is that happening?

Comment: Which browser are you trying it in? Do different browsers give different results?

Comment: Is that your non-working code? `actualkey == "8"` couldn't be 8 except you press the "8" on keyboard. Because you're converting the `charCode` to a String in this code. This works fine for me: [Fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/Pisi2012/63ekf8m0/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get Character value from KeyCode in Javascript…then trim](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5829387/1176601)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get Character value from KeyCode in Javascript...then trim](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1772179/get-character-value-from-keycode-in-javascript-then-trim)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce the phenomenon with the following code:

```
window.onkeydown=function(evt) {
    console.log(evt.keyIdentifier)
}
```

If I press the * key (also on the numpad) it produces the keyIdentifer U+004A which, in the UTF-8 Charset, equals the 'LATIN CAPITAL LETTER J'.

Also note that my code only works in Chrome.

In Firefox the `evt.key` correctly produces an Asterix and in both browsers `evt.keyCode` produces the Char Code 106, which according to google should equal 'multiply' but if converted using javascript actually produces 'j'.

This seems to be a javascript related issue.

I hope this information helps somebody out there.

Greetings
spitterfly

Edit: 
Found the following on the mozilla developer web page:

> Although most common Unicode values can be represented with one 16-bit
>   number (as expected early on during JavaScript standardization) and
>   fromCharCode() can be used to return a single character for the most
>   common values (i.e., UCS-2 values which are the subset of UTF-16 with
>   the most common characters), in order to deal with ALL legal Unicode
>   values (up to 21 bits), fromCharCode() alone is inadequate. Since the
>   higher code point characters use two (lower value) "surrogate" numbers
>   to form a single character, String.fromCodePoint() (part of the ES6
>   draft) can be used to return such a pair and thus adequately represent
>   these higher valued characters.

[Mozilla Reference fromCharCode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode)