# Get value on keydown or input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a textbox and I want to get the value of the key pressed. I use jQuery to allow the user to insert only numbers and letters even if copy/paste is used.
I'd like to get the letter or the number the user pressed.

```js
$("#Nombre").on("keydown", function(event) {
  var regexp = /[^A-Za-z0-9]+/g;
  if ($(this).val().match(regexp)) {
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(regexp, ''));
  } else {
    var Valor = $(this).val(); //get the value of keypressed here
  }
});

$("#Nombre").on("input", function() {
  var regexp = /[^A-Za-z0-9]+/g;
  if ($(this).val().match(regexp)) {
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(regexp, ''));
  } else {
    var Valor = $(this).val(); //get the value of keypressed here
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" class="form-control" id="Nombre" Maxlength=43 name="txtNombre" required>
```

Comment: Seems to work. What's the problem?

Comment: Are you saying that you want to know which key was pressed, even if it was one you're restricting?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan No, what I want is this: If the user pressed '5' I want to get the number 5. and so on.

Comment: Then I'm confused as your code does that already...? Also, I'm confused as to why you feel the need to duplicate the same logic, you can use a single `on()` call instead

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get Character value from KeyCode in JavaScript... then trim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1772179/get-character-value-from-keycode-in-javascript-then-trim)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On *keydown* you can use [`String​.from​Char​Code()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode) to get the character from `event.keyCode`. On *input* event you can get the last character from the value:

```js
$("#Nombre").on("keydown", function(event) {
  var regexp = /[^A-Za-z0-9]+/g;
  if ($(this).val().match(regexp)) {
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(regexp, ''));
  }
  else{
    var Valor = String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode)
    console.log(Valor);
  }
});

$("#Nombre").on("input", function() {
  var regexp = /[^A-Za-z0-9]+/g;
  if ($(this).val().match(regexp)) {
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(regexp, ''));
  }
  else{
    var val = $(this).val();
    var Valor = val[val.length -1];    
    console.log(Valor);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" class="form-control" id="Nombre" Maxlength=43 name="txtNombre" required>
```